# What is the proper date format for a rest api payload field?

Tags: rest, date-formatting

We are designing a rest api that will serve date fields, both in get and post requests.

So date fields will be present in the **body** of the http payloads.

As far as I know (correct me if I m wrong) there is no date data-type definition in json, it is just string. Thus it depends on the implementation what the format of this string-date fields will be.

But is there no best-practice for such cases? I find it difficult to locate a guideline. Can you help with this please?

UPDATE: This question is marked as duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581692/recommended-date-format-for-rest-get-api), but it is not, as I ask about the recommended date format of the PAYLOAD of a date field, while this other post discusses the format of the GET Request URI!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581692/recommended-date-format-for-rest-get-api

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd format should ideally be the best as there is no confusion regarding it

Comment: Yeah, JSON has no data type definition. You need to validate in back-end. The better way is passing date as timestamp.

Comment: @maio290, the post you suggest is not duplicate, I already checked it and it has to do with date in the uri for get requests specifically

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1179

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most commonly used format you will probably find is [ISO-8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Given its a widely adopted and recognised standard I'd say it's the way to go, particularly if your API is being consumed by unknown client applications.

Comment: Thank you James, I see now the Json-Schema approach, which suggests RFC-3339 (http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section?.7.3.1). Would you suggest ISO-8601 as most commonly adopted vs RFC-3339

Comment: @cnom The RFC 3339 [does recommend](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6) the ISO 8601 as the standard format for date and time.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin, thank you, I did see that. It only has minor differences. See my own answer, I just posted, it utilizes the advantages of JSON-SCHEMA (which follows rfc-3339)

Answer (score 1):

After some research, an alternative to ISO-8601 would be the **date-time format**, as proposed in the **json-schema.org**.

[Here](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.7.3.1) is the relevant documentation and it follows the

> RFC-3339

(which is a "profile" of ISO-8601)

The advantage of such standard formatting is that

1. it can be **easily validated**
2. it can be **clearly documented**

Comment: a "profile" of ISO 8601 is still ISO 8601 format ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You are right. Though my question is also about best practices, so I think the json-schema approach, is worth mentioned, even if it somewhat overlaps with the ISO-8601 :)