# Why most API use ISO-8601 timestamp format over epoch?

Tags: api, date, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I've seen a lot of projects where `epoch` format was used to represent dates. But as far as I know most of developers use `ISO-8601` format for timestamp. I wonder what benefits ISO-8601 has over epoch?

I found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37051167/7976987), but it's more about proper date formatting in general. I know epoch timestamps often used to represent last update or creation time - but I think it's rather about databases. For me epoch timestamp is a little confusing, at least because different languages utilize different time units (i.g. it's seconds in PHP, but milliseconds in Java, Javascript, etc.) while `ISO-8601` format is standard.

Comment: *while ISO-8601 is standard*. Yes, exactly. So that is what you should be using. If you need only the date, not the time, use the [calendar date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates), for example 2022-11-13. If you need a point in time, use [date and time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) in UTC and denote UTC by `Z`, for example 2022-11-13T12:34:56.7890Z.

Comment: What do you mean by a timestamp? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) *A timestamp is a sequence of characters or encoded information identifying when a certain event occurred, usually giving date and time of day, sometimes accurate to a small fraction of a second.* So of you need to convey a point in time, it seems some kind of timestamp is a good idea if not inevitable; but that still leaves countless options (of which, as I said, you should pick ISO 8601).

Comment: By timestamp here I meant time encoded in milliseconds or seconds. I actually used to think that timestamp was always encoded like that, but not anymore - thanks for the link. According to Wikipedia both Unix time and ISO 8601 are valid timestamps, just different formats. SO probably I should have named my question like "Should I use Unix time for timestamp in API"  (minding your first comment I understand I should not).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## tl;dr

Which value you would rather see when debugging a critical problem at 3 AM?

- `1668329462529`
- `2022-11-13T08:51:02.529Z`

## Use ISO 8601 text for clarity

Regarding the tracking of time using an elapsed count from some epoch reference, two issues to consider:

- Various granularities are used by various protocols such as whole seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, hundreds of microseconds, nanoseconds, etc.
- [Various epoch references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) are used by various systems/protocols.

So encountering a mere number that is supposed to represent a date-time can be ambiguous. Such numbers are often error-prone because of incorrect assumptions or miscommunications.

A mere number cannot be parsed as a moment by a human mind. A timestamp such as 15687402956 or 1668329058 is unreadable to mere mortals. So debugging is made difficult. And invalid values may go unnoticed.

Generally better to store and exchange date-time values as text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. This standard defines formats that are thoughtfully designed to be relatively clear and unambiguous across human cultures and languages.

### Offset of zero

And it is generally best to report moments (specific points on the timeline) with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds unless you have a specific reason to use offsets.

For example, in Java:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
String output = instant.toString() ;  // Generates text in ISO 8601 format.
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/bml6qB).

> 2022-11-13T08:17:31.634762Z

The `Z` at the end of an ISO 8601 string means an offset of zero, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

Going the other direction:

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2022-11-13T08:17:31.634762Z" ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`s

Note that one shortcoming of ISO 8601 is the omission of time zones. The standard covers only offsets.

The [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class in Java wisely extends the ISO 8601 standard to append the time zone name in brackets when generating text. One of the biggest advantages of `ZonedDateTime` over an `OffsetDateTime` is that it adjusts the time zone offset automatically (e.g. in the case of [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) or when a country changes its time zone offset).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
String output = now.toString() ;  // ISO 8601 format extended to append the name of the zone in brackets.
```

When [run in Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/bml6qB). Note the formal time zone name (`Continent/Region`) at the end.

> 2022-11-13T17:26:08.717876+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]

Hopefully, this representation of time zones will catch on as a *de facto* standard, and someday be added to the official standard.

### Definitions

A quick review of *offset* & *time zone*:

- An **offset** is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal prime meridian of UTC.
- A **time zone** is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region, as decided by their politicians.

## When to use count

The only place I would use a count as a way of tracking time would be where resources are extremely constrained. A count of milliseconds takes only 32-bits.

In commonplace business app programming, such a need has largely evaporated. Memory is cheap, storage is cheap.

In contrast, debugging is expensive, and business miscommunication is expensive. So use ISO 8601 text wherever practicable.

Comment: In additional favour of ISO 8601: In support and debugging situations one needs to read and understand the values transmitted. A Unix timestamp like 15687402956 or 1668329058 is unreadable to most of us, we need a converter. ISO like 2022-11-13T12:34:56.7890Z gives a rough idea, and most of us can even learn to convert to our own time zone in the head.

Comment: @OleV.V. I added a mention of your point. And I made a *tl;dr* of it. Thank you!